Connecting battery chargers in parallel with load?
I've seen a number of off-grid power supply systems that look something like this:

They have multiple charging sources connected to the battery in parallel with the nominal 12V load. Given that chargers put out a higher than nominal voltage in order to charge the battery (e.g., 14.6V for a lifepo4 charger), is this a problem? Should there be a dc/dc converter before the load to regulate the voltage to a constant value?

If a load is designed to be connected to a nominally 12V battery, then it'll work just fine at the higher voltage of a battery under charge.
If the load was designed by someone who heard "12V" and thought that meant that they'd get clean 12V power no matter what, it may not work well.
If it's designed for a 12V battery powered system, like a car or a truck or a boat or off grid, you're fine.
If it's designed to work from a 12V wall-wart, then you may have problems with it.

Virtually all loads meant to be powered from a "12V" battery count on its actual voltage range which can be anywhere from as low as 11V or less, and up to almost 15V.
Practically all of the circuits I have seen meant for a 12V supply are also capable of running at up to 16V, so I wouldn't see the circuit in your question as a problem.
There are probably VERY FEW circuits which might have a problem with it, though I can't think of one at the moment.
